# Getting all results from Selection made by Attribute or Location using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

Using arcpy I'm trying to get the results of a selection, or what is currently selected as a list.

Basically I'm attempting to build an addin which on click will either perform an operation where I invoke SelectLayerByAttribute_management (or ByLocation) to select some features, or the user performs a selection ByAttribute (or ByLocation), and while they have their selection hightlighted executes my snippet by pressing a button on the toolbar.  In each  case I want to get a list of results to perform a specific task on only certain selected features.

I can't find out how to get a list of the currently selected features, or find a listener for  selection having been made so I can enable the button, and ensure I can perform my operation on an existing selection.

Comment: This may have already been partially answered:

[Can I get a list of my selected features in ArcGIS by using Python code?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44733/can-i-get-a-list-of-my-selected-features-in-arcgis-by-using-python-code)

  Also see: [How to access data from a selected feature in ArcGIS 10?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/how-to-access-data-from-a-selected-feature-in-arcgis-10)

Comment: Hi, I've read and worked through those posts, but neither allow me to get the results of a selection made by a user unless I know which layer it was made in.  Is there a way to get a selection in an unknown layer with only knowing the .gdb?

Answer (score 10):

To iterate over the layers in the map, get a reference to the current map document and list the layers within it:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
for layer in layers:
   # do something with 'layer'
```

To just get the number of selected features, try leveraging the [`Describe`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) object's `fidSet` property:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
sel_count = len(desc.fidSet.split(";"))
```

You can check this count to determine whether any features are selected, or just do `if desc.fidSet:` which should accomplish the same.

To get a particular field's values for each selected feature within a layer, use a `SearchCursor` (either the [`arcpy.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018v00000050000000/) or [`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/) variety), which honors the selection on layers. See the other questions linked in the comments above.

Interactive session in ArcMap's Python window to demonstrate how you might do this:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
>>> for layer in layers:
...     desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
...     if desc.fidSet:
...         print layer.name, "has {0} features selected:".format(len(desc.fidSet.split(';')))
...         for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, "*"):
...             print row
...             
atlantic_hurricanes_2000 has 2 features selected:
(220, (-86.60000000039969, 30.500000000299735), datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 22, 0, 0), u'12:00:00', 30.5, -86.6, 1006.0, 35.0, u'tropical storm', u'Helene', datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 22, 12, 0))
(221, (-85.40000000009991, 31.599999999900035), datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 22, 0, 0), u'18:00:00', 31.6, -85.4, 1010.0, 25.0, u'tropical depression', u'Helene', datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 22, 18, 0))
atlantic_hurricanes_2000_lines has 1 features selected:
(8, (-70.38282674742592, 29.09090367649801), 84.23001922499401, u'Helene', 34.76190476190476, None)
```

Comment: This works well, but FIDSet will be set to `''` if no features are selected instead of `None`. This will result in a count of 1 (`''.split(';') == ['']`!) instead of 0 and `if desc.FIDSet` will also be true in that case (at least with ArcGIS 10.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could call ListLayers, then cycle through all possible layers and use the getSelectedExtent method, which returns an Extent object; if the extent isn't null/zero, the layer is selected.  Then you'd know which layer the user has selected, and you can use a cursor or CopyFeatures_management on them.  See the following links:

[Layer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000)

[Extent (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000072000000)

Hope this helps.