# Batch export all layers in ArcMap document that have selected features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, export, select

I have several layers in an ArcMap Document. All of these layers are stored as shape files.

Specific features of the said layers are selected. I want to export the data as shapefile programatically. How can I do this using arcpy?

[image: Sample view of my arcmap workspace]

Comment: The question is what do you want to use? ModelBuilder, python, C#, VB.net... it is kind of difficult in python/modelbuilder to see if a layer *has* a selection but not impossible (in python). ArcObjects (C#,VB.net) is easy to see the selection but unless you have some programming experience that's probably not going to help.

Comment: @Michael I want to use python, since I'm currently using arcpy packages.

Comment: To determine if a layer has a selection read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73173/how-do-you-get-all-the-results-from-a-selection-made-by-attribute-or-location-us it's to do with the FIDset... iterate through the map layers then use CopyFeatures to export the selected records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try..

```
    ## This script will look for all the layers that have feature selected in them in the TOC and export them in seperated shapefile.
    ##output layer name will be the original name+ _selected e.g. luzon_loss_selected
    import arcpy
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames( mxd, "Layers")[0]
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)
    output_folder = r'C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\Desktop\test' ##folder path of output
    for layer in layers:
        Sel=arcpy.Describe(layer)
        if Sel.FIDset: 
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer,output_folder,layer.name + "_selected","","","")
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP asks for exporting only selected features.  Not layers which are visible.

Comment: FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion exports only selected records. I used 'visible' property to check if the layer is turned on/off if turned on then it will export only selected records.

Comment: @SIslam It worked! I was exploring the arcpy.da.SearchCusor but this answer definitely solved my problem.

Comment: I edited the answer as asked the question.

Comment: +1 SIslam, the way you've written now is better.  However, you're incorrect about FeatureClassToFeatureClass.  It will only export selected features **if** there is a selection.  But if there is no selection, it will export the whole feature class.  But the way you've rewritten it, it appears you realise that.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, i intended to mean the function of that tool in the scope of my script.